# Background distorted

Tags: android

I'm using  android:background="@drawable/home_background"
but on switching the screen to landscape , the image gets distorted and stretched too much . The picture is a .jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use two images (one for portrait and one for landscape). In `onCreate(...)` of my `Activity` I use the following to set the correct image...

```
View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == orientation) {
    view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.bground_land);
} else {
    view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.bground_port);
}
```

`bground_land.jpg` and `bground_port.jpg` are the images in my project's /res/drawable directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to changed Aspect Ratio. Android recommends dedicated sets of images for landscape and portrait modes (also for low, media and high resolution screens). So you need to have a background picture suitable for landscape mode under res\drawable-land (portrait in drawable-port) folder.

Can refer to android sample apps for more clarity. For LunarLander App you can see that two sets of images were created, each for landscape and portrait mode. (android sdk..\samples\LunarLander\res)

Shash

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html try this.... or you also may make different drawables for either portraitmode or landscape mode.. or try different ressource-configurations like making a drawables folder for drawable-land and one named drawable-portrait